# Do French citizens need a visa or some other travel paperwork to attend a conference in Canada?

Tags: visas, air-travel, canada, borders, conferences

Do French citizens need a visa or some other travel paperwork aside from their passport to attend a conference in Canada?

I’m interested in entries by air and by land. I know that for tourism, they need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA) for entries by air.

Comment: What makes you think that the requirements for conferences would be any different than any other temporary visit?

Comment: @littleadv conference visas in India, working being disallowed when entering as a tourist or visa-free in some some countries and my 1 hour wait in the secondary last time I entered Canada by land because the presence of screen monitors in my back seats made them thought I was planning to work in Canada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In any case, a temporary resident visa (for visits, work or study) cannot be issued to a visa-exempt national. If they come to Canada by air, an electronic travel authorization is required (other than for a U.S. citizen or Lawful Permanent Resident).

Usually, the only issue, assuming standard admissibility requirements are met, is whether a work or study permit is required.

Foreign [business visitors](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/business/visitors-events-conferences.html), including those who attend conferences, do not require a work permit, if the following is met

> To qualify as a business visitor to Canada, you must show that
>
> - you plan to stay for less than 6 months
> - you don’t plan to enter the Canadian labour market
> - your main place of business, and source of income and profits is outside Canada
> - you have documents that support your application
> - you meet Canada’s basic entry requirements, because you
>
>   - have a valid travel document, such as a passport
>   - have enough money for your stay and to return home
>   - plan to leave Canada at the end of your visit
>   - are not a criminal, security or health risk to Canadians

Comment: @littleadv https://ircc.canada.ca/english/visit/visas.asp suggests that ETA is not required for US permanent residents.

Comment: @phoog the question is about French citizens. What does US permanent residency have to do with that?

Comment: @littleadv given all the questions Franck has asked on expatriates about naturalization in the US, and before that about obtaining a green card, it's fairly likely that the French citizen in question is a permanent resident.

Comment: @phoog and how would a random French citizen who came here from a google search know that you're just assuming that Franck is going to a conference? Why not just answer the question as asked without making assumptions?